# Access and Assign values into a text box contained within a Tabstrip Control

Tags: abap

In ABAP, I have built 3 screens: 0100, 0110, 0120

Screen 0100 is a Tabstrip Control with 2 tabs (each containing a Subscreen).
Screen 0100 calls Screen 0110

Screen 0110 contains two textboxes: value1, value2 and a pushbutton
Pressing the pushbutton takes me to tab2 of the tabstrip containing textbox result.

I want to add values of textbox: value1 and textbox: value2 and assign the result into textbox: result.

Question) How do i access values present in TabstripControlTab1-Subscreen-Textbox1(value1) and TabstripControlTab1-Subscreen-Textbox2(value2) and assign the calculated value into TabstripControlTab2-Subscreen-Textbox1(result)?

I have declared variables of same names as the textbox controls in TopInclude of the program: value1, value2, result all of integer type, but somehow values in the textboxs are not getting reflected into ABAP program variables.

Screen0110:

[image]

Screen0120:

[image]

---

*******Code:**********

```
Main Program: 

INCLUDE Z_DEMOSCREEN_TOP.    " global Data

*Screen 110 Include:
INCLUDE Z_DEMOSCREEN_STATUS_0100O01.
INCLUDE Z_DEMOSCREEN_USER_COMD_010I01.

*Screen 120 Include:
INCLUDE Z_DEMOSCREEN_STATUS_0110O01.
INCLUDE Z_DEMOSCREEN_USER_CMD_011I01.

START-OF-SELECTION.

CALL SCREEN 100.
```

---

```
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*& Include Z_DEMOSCREEN_TOP          Module Pool      Z_DEMOSCREEN
*&
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*

PROGRAM  Z_DEMOSCREEN.
DATA:
FIRST_VALUE TYPE C,
SECOND_VALUE TYPE I,
RESULT TYPE I,
ok_code LIKE sy-ucomm.
CONTROLS tabstrip TYPE TABSTRIP.
```

---

```
*****Screen 100:*****
PROCESS BEFORE OUTPUT.
 MODULE STATUS_0100.
 CALL SUBSCREEN TABSTRIP_TAB1_SUBSCR INCLUDING sy-cprog '0110'.


PROCESS AFTER INPUT.
 MODULE USER_COMMAND_0100.

module USER_COMMAND_0100 input.
  CLEAR: ok_code.
  ok_code = sy-ucomm.

  CASE ok_code.
    WHEN 'TAB1' OR 'TAB2'.
      tabstrip-activetab = ok_code.
    WHEN 'ADD'.
      tabstrip-activetab = 'TAB2'.
    WHEN 'BACK'.
      LEAVE TO SCREEN 0.
    WHEN 'CANCEL'.
      LEAVE TO SCREEN 0.
    WHEN 'EXIT'.
      LEAVE TO SCREEN 0.
  ENDCASE.
endmodule.
```

---

```
*** Screen 110***
PROCESS BEFORE OUTPUT.
 MODULE STATUS_0200.
*
PROCESS AFTER INPUT.
 MODULE USER_COMMAND_0200.
```

Comment: The values entered in the screen fields named `value1` and `value2` should directly be transferred to your global variables `value1` and `value2` (the transfer is done by name matching), but only if you defined your tabstrip control with the mode **server paging**. If you defined it with "local paging" and you switch between the tabs, the ABAP code is not called, values of screen fields are not transferred. Pressing Enter (or other alike function keys) will transfer the values.

Comment: give the code and screen definition

Comment: code added to the question

Answer (score 1):

I had to call both subscreens 110 and 120 at PBO
And at PAI I had to call subscreen 110

I am assuming, since just calling the subscreens at PBO (without a call statement at PAI) will call the subscreen 110 again each time I hit the push button PUSH, erasing previous entries.

**Code for Screen 100**

```
PROCESS BEFORE OUTPUT.
  MODULE status_0100.
  CALL SUBSCREEN tabstrip_tab1_subscr INCLUDING sy-cprog '0110'.
  CALL SUBSCREEN tabstrip_tab2_subscr INCLUDING sy-cprog '0120'.




PROCESS AFTER INPUT.
  MODULE user_command_0100.
  CALL SUBSCREEN tabstrip_tab1_subscr.
```

The global variables were shifted to TOP include.

Screens 110 and 120 will have no new menus or code.

Screen 120 PBO will have the calculation:
Result = First_Value + Second_Value

At PAI I could not use full call subscreen method:

```
CALL SUBSCREEN tabstrip_tab1_subscr INCLUDING sy-cprog '0110'.
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give element name as global variable such as GV_VALUE1 and GV_VALUE2. GUI automatically display variable values and it assign entered values to these variables.

Comment: I haven't included a top include in my module pool, but I have defined variables: value1, value2 and result at the main program defined with Report <report name> where all includes are called.

The screen fields are int1 type and the variables are integer (I) type.

Still the variables are not getting mapped to screen fields

Comment: @gram77 As far as I know `INT1` type is not supported in Dynpro technology. You should use `INT4` (only the latter corresponds to type `I` in ABAP code).